# jquery function not apply to load append page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function newFunction(ele){
    ele.each(function(){
        $(this).text('foo');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
   newFunction($('.text'));
});
```

I have a page have a function apply to all .text class,

this page also use jquery load & append data into it.

My problem is when jquery append new data from other page into this page.

this function didn't apply to the new data has .text class from other page.

Answer (score 0):

Yah that's the way it should work. It will append to what is already there on the DOM.
If you append new elements after the initial document load you have to call this function there just after appending new data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can add inside jquery load  function.

```
$( "#xyz" ).load( "xxy.html", function() {
newFunction($('.text'));
});
```

We can try

```
$(window).load(function(){
newFunction($('.text'));
})
```